# How can I hide apps in slingshot?

Tags: release-freya, slingshot, apps

My app launcher is quite full; Google Chrome adds a lot of apps to slingshot, and I don't use things such as the multitasking overview or the software centre. Is there any way I can hide these apps from view?

Comment: @Tim  don't use slingshot to launch Chrome apps at all, that's always done through the browser itself.

Comment: Just a little tip that could help someone else to avoids the mistake I just made : Type in "NoDisplay=true", because "...=True" won't work, it's case sensitive ! I changed a first time 25 .desktop files before realizing that! Have a good day, and I'm quite happy with Elementary, just want to point that out :-)

Comment: Easiest way to do it is to install "AppEditor" from elementary's appstore. You will find all the options in there.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

### Delete web application desktop entries added by Chrome

to get rid of all web application entries, open a terminal session and run

```
rm ~/.local/share/applications/chrome-*.desktop
```

to delete only a few of them, you'll have to take a look inside of each file and delete only the ones you want get rid of.

### Hide a desktop entry of a system application

if you want to hide an application like the multitasking overview, you have to copy it's .desktop file to your users local application folder:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop ~/.local/share/applications
```

edit the copied file:

```
scratch-text-editor ~/.local/share/applications/gala-multitaskingview.desktop
```

and add the following line:

```
NoDisplay=true
```

Comment: This does not seem to work on 0.4 Loki.

Comment: @RuppalSingh it still works in Loki, but a more comfortable way to do this task is to install and use `Menulibre`.

Comment: I have tried this on several icons that appear upon installing Calibre. None of them go away. I even have an ugly VIM icon I can't get rid of! Unless deleting the `.desktop` file is the only option...

Comment: @RuppalSingh you must be doing something wrong... I'm also hiding several Calibre icons and all of them disappear after adding `NoDisplay=true`. Please try using `Menulibre`, this application is self explanatory and it's a more convenient way to hide these icons.

Answer (score 4):

As you don't need to access them any more, you can remove the `.desktop` files from:

```
~/.local/share/applications
```

Anyway, to know what ones you want to remove, select them all and open properties. Then chose More and Click Execute, next to Owner and next to Group. The number should now be 774.

[image]

Their icons will change from the unknown file to the app logo:

[image][image]

Then you can delete the ones you no longer want.

Answer (score 0):

There are two places where `.desktop` files get stored: `/usr/share/applications/` (system-wide) and `~/.local/share/applications` (specific to the current user). Slingshot looks at those `.desktop` places and shows them.

Default applications get stored in the system wide one. Google Chrome is using the place specific for the current user.

In both of the cases, you can delete the shortcut by typing:

```
rm NAME.desktop
```

If you want to delete system wide shortcuts, you'll have to use `sudo` in front of the command.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the checkbox `Applications menu` when creating a Chrome application shortcut:

[image]

Comment: You don't think you can customise those, unfortunately.